# Adding -DVLA to the make command of appstream

Tags: arch-linux, make, pantheon, aur

Situation: I am building Pantheon from AUR on Arch Linux.

Problem: I have issues building appcenter-bzr. On appcenter-bzr's page, there is a comment saying to "You want to add the -DVLA flag to the make command of the appstream package arch linux'". I tried `make -DVLA appstream` after manually downloading appstream and it states that there are no such options

Question: I do not understand what it meant by that. Can someone enlighten me?

Additional information: I posted on Arch BBS and no one replied me so I turned to Unix StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the Makefile, it's hard to tell. But you should do this:

```
make appstream DVLA=
```

Comment: Ah yes, I finally found the tutorial (shame on me for not noticing) on the appstream Git.
We are supposed to run `cmake -DVAPI=ON ..` to do build cmake with Vala API.
But thank you!